# Ant compile create unwanted java class file

Tags: java, class, ant, build

My standard ant build have accidentally compile a sub class with erroneous file name. Below is the sample class.

```
public final class AdminResources
{

   public static final class APPLICATION
   {
            public static final class MESSAGEBLOCK
            {
               public static final String LEDGER = "application.admin.app.messageblock.ledger";
            }
    }
}
```

Partial sample from build.xml file.

```
<target name="Compile_Sources" depends="Init_Dir" description="Compile Sources">
    <javac
        debug="true"
        srcdir="${source.dir}"
        destdir="${build.dir}"
        classpathref="classpath">                   
    </javac>
</target>
```

Build process was running smoothly without error, but have produce additional unwanted file as below base on the above class sample.

- AdminResources.class **(this is ok)**
- AdminResources$APPLICATION.class
- AdminResources$APPLICATION$MESSAGEBLOCK.class

Below is the information on my environment.

- Ant version : 1.9.0
- Java : 1.7.0-u21

Comment: That is exactly how the java compiler creates from one .java file several .class files. For anonymous classes also something like `AdminResources$1.class`. It is OK.

Comment: Unwanted in which way?! Those are the classes *you* declared.

Comment: Sorry, it was my lack of understanding in large scale java development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ANT compilation: the two files are class files compiled from the inner classes of `AdminResources`. Even if you compile your program manually you would end up with one file per class, including anonymous classes that your program may have:

```
Class name                                File name
---------------------------------------   ---------------------------------------------
AdminResources                            AdminResources.class
AdminResources.APPLICATION                AdminResources$APPLICATION.class
AdminResources.APPLICATION.MESSAGEBLOCK   AdminResources$APPLICATION$MESSAGEBLOCK.class
```